# graphhoper maps for offline routing

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, offline, graphhopper

I'm trying to create an application  with graphhoper for offline routing .
This Application can download map of some countries for example  Now I have a directory with the extension "-gh", inside there are files: "edges", "nodes", "geometry" and a .map file. I want iran map and I downloaded iran.map from " http://download.mapsforge.org/maps/asia/  "and I downloaded some data (iran-latest.osm.bz2 , iran-latest.osm.pbf) from http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/iran.html   but I didn't find "edges", "nodes", "geometry" and ...  .

How can I convert iran-latest.osm.bz2 , iran-latest.osm.pbf to edges , nodes
 and ...?
what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Android documentation](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md) you have to execute `./graphhopper.sh import your-area.pbf` first in order to create the routing data.